# How do I concatenate strings through an overload * operator, where if I multiply an integer N with a string S, I should get S concatenated N times

Tags: c++11

I have to create an overload operator for multiplication, for all the types in my Value class. But I am not sure how I am supposed to code for multiplying a String, say S, with an integer, say N, where the return is the string S concatenated N times. This is what I have:

```
enum Type {
INTEGERVAL,
FLOATVAL,
STRINGVAL,
UNKNOWNVAL,
};

class Value {
int i;
float f;
string s;
Type t;
public:
Value(int i) : i(i), f(0), t(INTEGERVAL) {}
Value(float f) : i(0), f(f), t(FLOATVAL) {}
Value(string s) : i(0), f(0), s(s), t(STRINGVAL) {}

Type GetType() { return t; }
int GetIntValue();
float GetFloatValue();
string GetStringValue();


Value operator*(const Value& op) const
{
    if (t == INTEGERVAL)
    {
        // I can multiply with another integer or float
        if (op.t == INTEGERVAL)
            return Value(i * op.i);
        else if (op.t == FLOATVAL)
            return Value(i * op.f);
    }
    else if (t == FLOATVAL)
    {
        // I can multiply with another integer or float
        if (op.t == INTEGERVAL)
            return Value(f * op.i);
        else if (op.t == FLOATVAL)
            return Value(f * op.f);
    }
    else if (t == STRINGVAL)
    {
        if (op.t == INTEGERVAL)
        {
            //I can concatenate a string times the value of the integer

            //Not sure how to do it//
            return Value(); //I don't know what the return should be//
        }
    }
    return Value(); // invalid!
}
};
```

I'd really appreciate some guidance on how this is supposed to be done.
Please let me know if I need to provide any other information regarding this code, or if I need to state my question in a better way =)

Thank You All!

Comment: nobody knows how strings are stored in your `Value` class.  Do you have a `std::string` member?  A `char*`?  Some other form of string?

Comment: In general though, find the length of the string operand, multiply that by the integer to find the length of the result.  Allocate / prereserve the space, and then do string copy that many times into the output string.

Comment: Thank You @BenVoigt. I really appreciate the response. I included the parts of the Value class that are appropriate to this question. Would what you said still work, now that the Value class has been included?

Comment: Sure: The preallocation would look like `v.s.reserve(s.size() * op.i)` and the copy would look like `v.s.append(s)` (do it `op.i` times)

Comment: Thank you so much @BenVoigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary string and `for` loop

 Assuming you have integer value stored in `i` and you want to concatenate `op.s`

```
else if (t == STRINGVAL)
    {
        if (op.t == INTEGERVAL)
        {
            string temp;  //Create a temporary string
            //Optional but would be useful for reallocating
            temp.reserve(op.s.length()*i);
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)  //Assuming " i " has the count
                temp += op.s;     //This will concatenate

            return Value(temp);  //Pass the newly created string 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Sniper That seems to have worked perfectly!

Comment: Better to reserve the space in advance, since you know exactly how much will be needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree but according to  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/  `operator+=` for string **Extends the string by appending additional characters at the end of its current value**

Comment: @Sniper: Yes, but that means that string might internally have to reallocate and copy up to N times.  Much better to do `temp.reserve(s.size() * op.i)` up front, one allocation, no extra copies beyond the necessary ones.

Comment: It's not that append won't work without reserve, but reserve stops you from allocating more memory than necessary. In cases where the behavior is to double the size each time it could be a significant amount.

Comment: Note that your code also makes `i+1` copies, and it reads the count from the string operand and the string from the integer operand.

Comment: @BenVoigt addressed `i+1` copies issue